# WCF NamedPipe: PerSession-Single or Singleton-Multiple

Tags: wcf, performance, concurrency, netnamedpipebinding

I'm building web application (in this context the client) which talk with a different process (in this context the server) through a namedpipe wcf service (WCF 4).

After reading many articles I was thinking to create a pool of proxy connected to the server (I've read it provide better performance) used in roundrobin.

Each call will be very short, on the server i need to reads and writes simple properties on few objects but this objects are shared so i must use locks in any case.
I expect very high concurrency.

Beacuse of the pool, the client will have N session always open with server.

I was wondering what should be the best settings for InstanceContext-ConcurrencyMode between PerSession-Single or SingleInstance-Multiple.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion: Do not use custom pool of proxies. Use build-in [pooling of connections](http://kennyw.com/work/indigo/173). You can't fully control connectionPooling in predefined bindings but you have full control in customBinding when using [namedPipeTransport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788994.aspx).

From implementation perspective in your client - use new proxy for each client's request. Don't share proxies among requests.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know there were a built-in pool, I was almost sure to have read that there wasn't. This will save a me some development time and troubles. Do you think it will be better to go with a Single Instance Multithreaded service ?

Comment: Base on your description I think you can use singleton instance with multiple concurrency mode. You will have to deal with locks anyway.